# Nest can't resolve DataSource as dependency

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I've had a problem with dependencies in NestJS. On launch my NestJS app, compiler throw me this:

```
[Nest] 16004  - 09.04.2022, 16:14:46   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AccountService (MailingService, ?). Please make sure that the argument DataSource at index [1] is available in the AccountModule context.
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my modules:

```
@Module({
  imports: [],
  providers: [AccountService, MailingService],
  controllers: [AccountController],
  exports: []
})
export class AccountModule {}

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useClass: TypeOrmConfigService,
    }),
  ],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}

@Module({
  imports: [
    DatabaseModule,
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: '.env',
    }),
    ScheduleModule.forRoot(),
    AccountModule,
    AuthModule,
    MailingModule],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

thanks for any help!

PS. `DataSource` is a class from TypeORM to make query, earlier it was `Connection` class

Comment: I just started using nest, and I think they are just using the old version of Typeorm where Connection is no longer used.

Answer (score 7):

The docs are not very clear on this, but i figured out you can use the `@InjectDataSource()` decorator from `@nest/typeorm` package.

example:

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import { InjectDataSource } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot(), UsersModule],
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(
    @InjectDataSource()
    private dataSource: DataSource
  ) {}
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me. I initialize the datasource with TypeOrmModule.forRoot in the App.module. And I try to import the data source in another module...

Answer (score 6):

The first step we have to create database providers.

**database.providers.ts**

```
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';

export const databaseProviders = [
    {
        provide: DataSource,
        useFactory: async () => {
            // You can inject config service to provide dynamic DataSourceOptions
            const dataSource = new DataSource({
                type: 'mysql',
                host: 'localhost',
                port: 3306,
                username: 'root',
                password: 'root',
                database: 'test',
                entities: [
                    __dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}',
                ],
                synchronize: true,
            });
            try {
                if (!dataSource.isInitialized) {
                    await dataSource.initialize();
                }
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error?.message);
            }
            return dataSource;
        }
    }
];
```

Now we can import/export our database providers inside DatabaseModule.

database.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { databaseProviders } from './database.providers';

@Module({
    providers: [...databaseProviders],
    exports: [...databaseProviders],
})
export class DatabaseModule {}
```

Now, We can Inject DataSouce dependency into any feature module.
i.e. `photo.module.ts`

Note: Do not forgot to import `DatabaseModule` inside `PhotoModule`.

Comment: Sometimes, it's better to do things the manual way; almost threw in the towel in favor of Java Spring Boot. Perfect solution for me. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 6):

The correct approach is to provide a Custom DataSource Factory as the official documentation explains [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#custom-datasource-factory).

```js
 TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      // Use useFactory, useClass, or useExisting
      // to configure the DataSourceOptions.
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        type: 'mysql',
        host: configService.get('HOST'),
        port: +configService.get('PORT'),
        username: configService.get('USERNAME'),
        password: configService.get('PASSWORD'),
        database: configService.get('DATABASE'),
        entities: [],
        synchronize: true,
      }),
      // dataSource receives the configured DataSourceOptions
      // and returns a Promise<DataSource>.
      dataSourceFactory: async (options) => {
        const dataSource = await new DataSource(options).initialize();
        return dataSource;
      },
    });
```

Comment: I have a question tho, typeorm cli needs an instance of dataSource, if we are going with this example how can I use typeorm cli? `"typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs --dataSource app.module.ts"`???

Comment: @Gerard_dev this was exactly what I was missing in order to ger ConfigModule working with Datasource, Entities and Migrations. Thanks a lot, now everything is working.

Answer (score 5):

I created my own TypeOrmModule:

```
import { Global, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import { typeOrmConnectionDataSource } from './typeorm-datasource';

@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: DataSource,
      useFactory: async () => {
        await typeOrmConnectionDataSource.initialize();
        return typeOrmConnectionDataSource;
      },
    },
  ],
  exports: [DataSource],
})
export class TypeOrmModule {}
```

Here is "./typeorm-datasource" (but replace by your configuration):

```
import { DataSource } from "typeorm"

export const typeOrmConnectionDataSource = new DataSource({
  name: "default",
  type: "postgres",
  host: "localhost",
  port: 15432,
  username: "postgres",
  password: "postgres",
  database: "postgres",
  synchronize: false,
  schema: "my-schema",
  migrationsRun: false,
  entities: [`${__dirname}/**/**.entity{.ts,.js}`],
  migrations: [`${__dirname}/migrations/**/*{.ts,.js}`],
});
```

Comment: Hi, what is inside typeorm-datasource?

Comment: @Alopwer - I updated my anwser.

Comment: @Alopwer I have also explained how to resolved DataSource as dependency. You can check my answered. I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve it, the problem was in `DataSource` class, the docs tell us that: `DataSource is a pre-defined connection configuration to a specific database. You can have multiple data sources connected (with multiple connections in it), connected to multiple databases in your application.`. So, we can't use this class as a provider to make queries to our entites.

Inthe earlier versions of the `TypeORM` we can use `Connection` class, but right now the best choice is to use `EntityManager` instaed of `DataSource` or deprecated `Connection`

Comment: Do you have an example with the entitymanager?

Comment: If you have just one database connection it is fine to provide only the main DataSource as a provider. Otherwise you need a DataSource factory as a provider (create a class DataSourceFactory), that will resolve a different DataSource based on a parameter you must provide (like a string).

Comment: Please provide an example in the form of code snippets if this solution worked for you

Answer (score 0):

You need to export AccountService

```
@Module({
  imports: [],
  providers: [AccountService, MailingService],
  controllers: [AccountController],
  exports: [AccountService] // here
})
export class AccountModule {}
```